# Tried to compile MPIR, got 602 warnings

Tags: gmp

I'm trying to compile MPIR (dll_mpir_gc) for windows (config: x64, release) in VS2010 Professional, and get 602 warnings. Most of them are about precision loss, e.g.  "warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'mp_bitcnt_t' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data". Is this normal when compiling this lib?

Edit: 18 hours later, I posted this at https://groups.google.com/group/mpir-devel/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Brian is 'Yes, it's normal', 
https://groups.google.com/group/mpir-devel/browse_thread/thread/ee6d5a145c5b2088